# Silverlight 5 and Business Application

Tags: silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS11 Beta and trying to create a SL5 Business Application.  It throws up a message box saying I need to download the latest version of Silverlight.  So, I do this and then try to install it.  It then tells me that I have a later version of Silverlight and can't install.  I try to open my project and back comes the message box saying I have to re-download the installer.  Without uninstalling Silverlight, is there any other way around this?